# How to use takeWhile in python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm not getting the right answer but I cant figure out where is my problem

```
def GC_content(genetic_string):
    """
    :param genetic_string:
    :return: GC content in percentage
    :testmod

    >>> GC_content("CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTCAGACCAGCCCGGACTGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT")
    60.919540
    """
    counter = 0.0
    for index in takewhile(lambda x: x is "C" or x is "G", list(genetic_string)):
        counter += 1.0

    return  counter/float(len(genetic_string))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for:

```
s = list(genetic_string)
return (s.count('G') + s.count('C')) / float(len(s)) * 100
```

`takewhile` only takes characters from the beginning of the iterable (string) as long as the given condition holds but you wish to be looking at the whole string. In other words, `takewhile` isn't very suitable if you wish to come up with that 60.919540 result.

Comment: Yes, but I wanna know why my implementation with takewhile is not working. i need to see where is my error

Comment: @jd1215: as I said, takewhile only takes characters from the beginning of the string as long as the condition is true. Hence it won't go over the entire string, it'll just stop once it finds a character that doesn't meet the condition.

Answer (score 1):

takewhile is not working because it only returns all the matches up **until** the first non-match.

```
In [8]: gc = 'CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTCAGACCAGCCCGGACTGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT'

In [9]: list(takewhile(lambda x: x is "C" or x is "G", gc))
Out[9]: ['C', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code must looking like this to work as needed:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def GC_content(genetic_string):
    """
    :param genetic_string:
    :return: GC content in percentage
    :testmod

    >>> GC_content("CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTCAGACCAGCCCGGACTGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT")
    60.919540
    """
    counter = 0.0

    for c in list(genetic_string):
        if(c == 'C' or c=='G'):
            counter += 1.0

    return  counter/float(len(genetic_string)) * 100


result = GC_content("CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTCAGACCAGCCCGGACTGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT")
print(result)    # 60.91954022988506
```

takewhile returns elements until predicate return "FALSE" first time(i.e. counter will be increased only two times - for first "CC" letters). To understand there is same part of code with logic same as when using "takewhile"

```
for c in list(genetic_string):
    if(c == 'C' or c=='G'):
        counter += 1.0
    else:
        break
```

Also you are forgotten to to multiply result to 100, and "Is" operator not for comparison of values - it compare TYPES of values(checking that "integer is not string" for example)